# Can I access the current user in session statically in Quarkus?

Tags: security, quarkus, principal

I need to do access to the current user (previously set up by a `ContainerRequestFilter`) in a static way, to avoid the passage of the `@Context SecurityContext` in every method of every controller.

I want to achieve something that, in Spring, I would do with

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Is there any way to do it, besides using Spring Security in Quarkus?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you can manipulate the instance of `SecurityIdentity` to "make it static"

```
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserUtilsService {

@Inject
private SecurityIdentity securityIdentity;

private static SecurityIdentity instance;

/**
 * Gets the custom user.
 *
 * @return the custom user
 */
public static CustomUser getCustomUser() {
    return (CustomUser) instance.getPrincipal();
}

@PostConstruct
private void setUp() {
    instance = this.securityIdentity;
}
```

}

`@StartUp` does instantiate the bean on application start (instead of lazily).

You can then access to the Principal statically using `UserUtilsService.getCustomUser();`

Comment: but doesn't it mean you still need to inject the service where you need to call this service? So in a simple POJO this won't be possible... or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: You don't need to inject it, you can use the static method.
"this.securityIdentity" is initialized on startup (@Startup) and assigned to the static field. It's basically a workaround to access it statically.

Comment: but is it request scoped or ?

Comment: It is request scoped

Comment: interesting. I look at your implementation and without proper injection to me it seems as if it would not work, but you state otherwise. I will need to try this out myself I guess.